# How do I open an array of PDF files in Illustrator without user confirmation of prompts using javascript/extendscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I want to open an array of files in Illustrator without prompts and apply the preference of the page number to open using Javascript.

I've tried setting the PDF open options but that doesn't seem to suppress the prompt. It also doesn't seem to apply the options.

```
var pdfOptions = app.preferences.PDFFileOptions;
pdfOptions.pDFCropToBox = PDFBoxType.PDFBOUNDINGBOX;
pdfOptions.pageToOpen = 1;
    if (file != null) {
    var docRef = open(file, DocumentColorSpace.CMYK);
}
```

When I set "pageToOpen" to 3 it doesn't even pre-select that in the prompt that pops up asking for a choice of which page to open. However I don't want that to pop up at all. I need to open the first page of all the files, get some information and close the files without human interaction.

```
var pdfOptions = app.preferences.PDFFileOptions;
pdfOptions.pDFCropToBox = PDFBoxType.PDFBOUNDINGBOX;
pdfOptions.pageToOpen = 1;
// Open a file using these preferences
if (file != null) {
    var docRef = open(file, DocumentColorSpace.CMYK, pdfOptions);
}
```

The code above causes an error: "unknown open options found". These are examples from the illustrator programming guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;
```

It appears the prompt isn't affected by the preferences but if you turn off the interaction level with that line it respects the pdf open preferences.

Comment: Props!  Can you mark your question as answered so other people can reference it?

Comment: In Photoshop scripting, the equivalent "don't display" is: `app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;`